# Lucas numbers relation to Φ

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

So, the Lucas numbers are 2,1,3,4,7,11... Let L(n) be nth lucas number

Fibonacci numbers are 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21...

Φ^n=F(n+1)+F(n-1), F=Fibonacci number and n=nth

So, if I say n=5, then Φ^n=F(6)+F(4)=11 (8+3).

11=6th Lucas number.

For n=10, Φ^n=F(11)+F(9)=89+34=123 =L(11)

Again, Φ^n=L(n+1)

So, Φ^n=F(n+1)+F(n-1)=L(n+1). How is L(n)=Φ^n?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You start from a wrong equation and hence the derived results are also incorrect. The correct relation should have read $\phi^n = F_n \phi + F_{n-1}$, but there are many other relations from which. you can start. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number for many relations between these series and $\phi$.

Comment: could you please then derive Φ^n=L(n) instead of Φ^n=L(n+1)?. And this eqn Φ^n=FnΦ+F(n-1) was on numberphile, and I have assumed that n is very very large

Comment: So if I take the fibonacci series as 0,1,1.... then I can get the relation of Φ^n=L(n), but by taking powers of Φ and rounding to nearest whole numbers, I still get Φ^n=L(n+1)

Comment: $L_n = \phi^n + (-1/\phi)^n$ (this follows from solving the recurrence relation, but can also be proven by induction), this means that $L_n \approx \phi^n $ for large values of $n$ and the larger $n$ is the smaller the error in that. For small values of $n$ it doesn't work so good and hence you get the mistakes you found above.

Comment: Sir, I am asking which of the relations is correct-
ϕ^n=L(n) or ϕ^n=L(n+1)

Comment: I have given my reasoning for ϕ^n=L(n+1). Kindly point out the error

Comment: They are both incorrect, $\phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ that means $\phi^n$ can not be an integer for any integer $n \neq 0$. However, for very large values of $n$ the value of $\phi^n$ gets closer and closer to an integer value, i.e., for $n \rightarrow \infty$ you find $\phi^n  - L_n \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily show that ø+1/ø = sqrt(5), and by beniot's formula, you have Lucas = Fibonacci * sqrt(5).

Using base ø, such that 11 = 100, you can show that 10.1 square = 5, as

```
10.1² =  102.01  = 13.01 = 4.11 = 5.
```

Comment: Who is *beniot* ?

Comment: The Fn = phi^n/sqrt(5) formula.

Comment: This does not tell me who is this mathematician

Comment: binet. is the name to look for, sorry.  Beniot determined the second gallon and litre.

Comment: i dont think this answers my question

Comment: Are you sure that this new one is nor *Benoit* ?

Comment: I don't use the formula myself, rather use exact values.  It might be benoit.